# vim omnicomplete with ruby only partially works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, intellisense, omnicomplete

I have a +ruby version of vim 7.2 (also tried with 7.3 and custom compiled version) but I am only getting the omnicomplete (ctrl-x ctrl-o) to work in certain instances.

For example, if I have

```
class MegaGreeter
    attr_accessor :names

    def initialize(names = "world")
        @names = names
        if @names.nil?
            puts "hello #{@names}.each"
        end
    end
end
```

omnicomplete works for `.each`, but not for `.nil`.  Also, it won't auto complete any `attr_` keywords.

I have tried it with all my plugins disabled, again with all of them enabled.  I have tried it also with the vim-ruby plugin.  The plugins I have installed are AfterColors, CSApprox, surround, color_sample_pack, mimicpak, taglist.

I have the following section in my .vimrc (I can post entire .vimrc if needed).  I also use VIM for C++, JavaScript, and about a 1/2 dozen other languages, so there is omnicomplete stuff in there for some of them too:

```
" ============================ "
"   CTAGS / OMNICOMPLETE
" ============================ "

" map <ctrl>+F12 to generate ctags for current folder:
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR><CR>
" add current directory's generated tags file to available tags
set tags+=./projects/.tags
" toggle list view
map <F4> :TlistToggle<cr> 
" auto close omnicomplete options when exiting insert mode
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
" configs for cpp
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete with .
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete with ->
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete with ::
let OmniCpp_SelectFirstItem = 2 " select first item (but don't insert)
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 2 " search namespaces in this and included files
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function prototype (i.e. parameters) in popup window

if has("win32")
    let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='c:\programs\ctags\ctags58\ctags.exe'
else
    if has("win32unix")
    let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/bin/ctags.exe'
    else
    if has("unix")
        let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/bin/ctags'
    endif
    endif
endif

" omnicomplete settings for the popout menu
setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
" makes list show longest matching item at top of list
set completeopt=menuone,longest
" makes enter select item
inoremap <expr> <CR>    pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
inoremap <expr> <Space> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<Space>"
inoremap <expr> <.> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<.>"
inoremap <expr> <S-CR>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>\<C-y>" : ""
"manual up/down with tab & shift+tab
inoremap <expr> <Tab>   pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : ""
"allows for autoselect of first item in user complete list
inoremap <expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : '<C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
"allows autoselect of first item for omni complete
inoremap <expr> <leader>' pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : '<C-x><C-o><C-n><C-p><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
" open omni completion menu closing previous if open and opening new menu without changing the text
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> (pumvisible() ? (col('.') > 1 ? '<Esc>i<Right>' : '<Esc>i') : '') .
            \ '<C-x><C-o><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-n>\<lt>C-p>\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
" open user completion menu closing previous if open and opening new menu without changing the text
inoremap <expr> <S-Space> (pumvisible() ? (col('.') > 1 ? '<Esc>i<Right>' : '<Esc>i') : '') .
            \ '<C-x><C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-n>\<lt>C-p>\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'

" autocomplete for commands; and put most likely at top using tab complete
" (like windows cmd)
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest

" for ruby 
if has("autocmd")
    filetype indent on
    autocmd FileType cucumber,rspec,ruby set number
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_object = 1
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_include_objectspace = 1
    autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
else
    set autoindent
endif

" ruby requires bash --login; 
" This is to correct running cmd from vim via :!
if has("unix")
    set shell=/bin/bash\ -il
endif

"ruby end
```

So, is there a way I can get full support for Ruby in omnicomplete, if so how? Or, is this the most that omnicomplete has to offer for Ruby?

Comment: I'm hoping someone has a real answer for you, but in my experience, all of the completion solutions in Vim fall short. They're not very smart, and generally are not context-sensitive.  They work pretty well for completing based on CTAGS and loaded files, but don't analyze classes to find appropriate methods.  Once you've typed something once in the current session, or loaded a tagged file, they're pretty good at general string completion.  It's not the same as Java completion in IDEA or anything, though.

Comment: Try installing [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby), then setting `autocmd FileType ruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete`. I use [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim), but a setup involving the above works quite nicely for me — including completion for `.nil` and `.attr`, as you mentioned were problematic.

Comment: Vim autocomplete is generally pretty weak compared to most IDEs. In particular with Ruby, because it's a dynamic language and there aren't any good autocomplete libraries. The closest language is Python, and the only way to get good completion there is with [jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi), which [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) uses to great effect. The short answer is that there is no good Vim Ruby completion. I recommend using YouCompleteMe anyway, because it's incredibly fast and automatically uses tags, at least.

Comment: Also, get with the 2010s and upgrade to Vim 7.4. At least you'll have more plugin options.

Answer (score 2):

Vim auto-completion should work out of the box, I am not aware of any method `.nil` so I wouldn't be sure if that's a real issue.

However with regards to the omnicompletion not completing `attr_reader` and the likes, the `setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete` fixes it, however it should go in a `ftplugin/ruby/my_custom_ruby_ftplugin.vim` instead of just in your vimrc, or alternatively if you like you could put that setl command within a `autocmd FileType ruby setl omnifunc=syntaxcompelete#Complete` in your vimrc and it should then work like you expect.